# No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I am getting below error.

```
Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?
    at DialogflowConversation.response (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:162:19)
    at DialogflowConversation.serialize (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:134:89)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:154:28)
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I will post my code, in this i have used promise. please correct me if i am wrong in promise implementation.

```
public  getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv: any) : any {
            this.getDataFromDatabase(conv).then((todaysEntry) => {
                conv.ask('<speak>Welcome to my applicatoion <break time="1"/> </speak>');
                let question:Question =  this.getStartQuestion(1);
                conv.ask('<speak>'+question.ask+'</speak>');
                conv.data.kind  = question.resolution.kind;
                return question;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting document', err);
                return err;
             });

        }
```

code of the method "getDataFromDatabase"

```
public async getDataFromDatabase(conv: any) : Promise<any> {
            let getPromise  =   await this.getDAOaccess(conv);
            return getPromise;
        }
```

code of the method getDAOaccess

```
private getDAOaccess(conv:any) : Promise<any>{
            return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject) => {
                this.getDataFromDB(conv,(err:any,response:any)=>{
                    if(err)
                        reject(err);
                    else
                        resolve(response);
            });
        });

        }
```

code of the method getDataFromDB

```
private getDataFromDB(conv:any, callback: (err:any,response:any) => void ) : Promise<any> {
            let  self    =   this;
            let documentDetail;
            let subjectId    =   conv.request.user.userId;
            let questionID   =   conv.request.user.questionID;
            let docRef=  this.dbManager.collection('question').doc(subjectId);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                docRef.get().then(doc => {
                   documentDetail  =   doc;
                   conv.user.response= doc.data();
                   return resolve(doc.data());
                })
                .catch(err => {
                   console.log('Error getting document', err);
                   reject(err);
                });

            });
        }
```

Please let me know the issue in the code. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `getTodaysEntryOfUser()` is not returning a Promise. Assuming this is the intent handler (you don't show how you've registered it, if so), the Dialogflow library treats functions that don't return a Promise as if they were all synchronous operations and process it immediately.

If you are making async calls you need to make sure:

1. You make the calls to `conv.ask()` as part of resolving the Promise
2. You return a Promise

in this case, it might be as simple as making sure you've put `return` before the line

```
this.getDataFromDatabase(conv).then(
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `getDataFromDB` appears confused. You have defined a parameter `callback` which is then never used. Instead the method returns a `Promise` but when you call it you are ignoring the returned value as you are passing in the unused `callback` parameter.

Change `getDAOaccess` to use the `Promise`:

```
private getDAOaccess(conv:any) : Promise<any>{
        return this.getDataFromDB(conv);
    }
```

Now it becomes apparent that `getDAOaccess` does nothing at all so you can probably eliminate it from your code and simply call `getDataFromDB` directly from `getDataFromDatabase`.

This code is also confused. It returns a `Promise` so you don't actually have to `await` the inner call, just return the `Promise` that it returned.

```
public async getDataFromDatabase(conv: any) : Promise<any> {
        let getPromise  =   await this.getDAOaccess(conv);
        return getPromise;
    }
```

Should be:

```
public getDataFromDatabase(conv: any) : Promise<any> {
        return this.getDataFromDB(conv);
    }
```

and now you see this method does nothing either.

Now the outer call has a problem. You want to return a result, but the inner call is asynchronous. Probably the best thing is to mark this method as `async`:

```
public async getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv: any) {
    const todaysEntry = await this.getDataFromDB(conv);
    conv.ask('<speak>Welcome to my applicatoion <break time="1"/> </speak>');
    let question:Question =  this.getStartQuestion(1);
    conv.ask('<speak>'+question.ask+'</speak>');
    conv.data.kind  = question.resolution.kind;
    return question;
}
```

This method now returns a `Promise<Question>` which you need to handle as any other `Promise` wherever you call `getTodaysEntryOfUser` (if the database call fails the `Promise` will reject and the rejection just propogates upwards so no need to `return err` anywhere. Notice that you don't have to tell the compiler the return type, it will correctly work it out for itself. Also you should avoid declaring any parameters as type `any`, figure out the actual types for better error messages.

Comment: still i am getting same issue

Comment: I think, issue is with google Assistant is not waiting for long time to get response from Promise, After that error, i can print output using console.log